# Understanding calculation of "expected log predictive density"

Tags: bayesian, posterior

Suppose, I have a posterior distribution of parameters $\theta$, $P(\theta|y)=\frac{P(y|\theta)P(\theta)}{\int_\theta P(y|\theta)P(\theta)d\theta}$. Now, in order to assess the fit of the model, I want to calculate the "out of sample" expected log predictive density using a "new dataset", $z$.

In my understanding the steps of calculating expected log predictive density is as below:

suppose we sampled $M$ ($M$ is large) number of posterior samples
of parameters from the posterior distribution $P(\theta|y)$. Now we calculate the amount:

$$PLD= \frac{1}{M} \sum_{i=1}^{M} log P(z|\theta_i); \theta_i \sim P(\theta|y).$$

And this amount $PLD$ is the expected log predictive density. Am I right?

Comment: Just a small comment are you sure $P(\theta|y) = \int_{\theta}P(y|\theta)P(\theta)d\theta$ ?? Because you integrate out the parameter $\theta$

Comment: @Fiodor1234 THANKS! How could I forget the numerator!

Comment: no worries such things happen to everyone :)

Comment: @Fiodor1234 :). But is my concept of calculating the "expected log posterior density" correct?

Comment: Do you mean the expected log posterior predictive density?? Because I haven't heard of expected log posterior density

Comment: @Fiodor1234 exactly! I am talking about "expected log posterior predictive density?"

Comment: Then you want to calculate the $\mathbb{E}_{p(\theta|Data)}[log(p(y_{new}|Data))]=\int_{\theta} log(p(y_{new}|\theta))p(\theta|Data)d\theta$

Comment: Then if you simulate $\theta_{i}\sim p(\theta|Data)$ the expected value should be approximated by $\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^{M}log(p(y_{new}|\theta_{i}))$, so yes you are correct

Comment: @Fiodor1234 YES!!! THANK YOU so much!

Comment: Check also this https://vasishth.github.io/bayescogsci/book/expected-log-predictive-density-of-a-model.html, might help

Comment: The expectation in "expected log posterior density" should be in terms of the distribution of $y_\text{new}$.

Comment: @Xian, I wanted to discuss the term "expected log predictive density". I corrected it in my heading.